# Python Global Variable not updating

Tags: python, global-variables

I'm new with Python and programming but I can't seem to understand why this function does not update the global variable

```
global weight
weight = 'value'
def GetLiveWeight():
    SetPort()
    while interupt == False:
        port.write(requestChar2)
        liveRaw = port.read(9)
        liveRaw += port.read(port.inWaiting())
        time.sleep(0.2)
        weight = liveRaw.translate(None, string.letters)
    return weight
```

I also tried this:

```
weight = 'value'
def GetLiveWeight():
    global weight
    SetPort()
    while interupt == False:
        port.write(requestChar2)
        liveRaw = port.read(9)
        liveRaw += port.read(port.inWaiting())
        time.sleep(0.2)
        weight = liveRaw.translate(None, string.letters)
    return weight

try:
    threading.Thread(target = GetLiveWeight).start()
    print liveWeight
except:
    print "Error: unable to start thread"
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to declare that `weight` is global *inside* `GetLiveWeight`, not outside it.

```
weight = 'value'
def GetLiveWeight():
    global weight
```

The [`global` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) tells Python that within the scope of the `GetLiveWeight` function, `weight` refers to the global variable `weight`, not some new local variable `weight`.

Comment: Thanks I had tried that, but still I cannot seem to get the function to change the weight variable it always seems to stay set to value?

Comment: Are you sure the condition `interupt == False` (which is more commonly written as `not interupt`) is ever True? In other words, are you sure the code inside the `while-loop` is getting executed?

Comment: yes, I added a print into the while loop to output the variable weight and it works fine. It may have something to do with the way that I am calling it 'try:
        threading.Thread(target = GetLiveWeight).start()
        print liveWeight
    except:
        print "Error: unable to start thread"'

Comment: The print statement inside the `try`-suite is getting executed *before* the other thread modifies `weight`.