# Globally scoped variable not returning updated version

Tags: python

My variable value_knap is updating within the scope of the while loop. But when I access its value outside the while loop it just goes back to its original value. I thought that I made it into a global variable with the scope of the function. I've tried reading other blog post like [Python Global not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911831/python-global-variable-not-updating) and the python [read thed ocs](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) python tutorial. I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

```py
def get_optimal_value (capacity, values, weights):

  #values for each item v/w by index
  val_item =[]

  #the total value of the knapsack
  value_knap = 0

  #while the bag is not full - when capacity is greater 0
  #calculate the value of each item
  #find the value of each weight
  for i in range (len (weights)):
      ratio = values[i] / weights[i] 
      val_item.append([ratio, weights[i]])

  #sort from largest to smallest    
  val_item.sort(reverse = True)
  #print(val_item)

  #while there are items available go through the list of loot items >:)
  while len(val_item) > 0:

      #if the weight is more than the capacity of the loot bag
      #return a fraction of the value of the item

      if capacity<val_item[0][1]:
          capacity = capacity / val_item[0][1]
          #print(val_item)
          value_knap = capacity * values[0] 
          val_item.pop(0) 

      #if the the bag can hold the the entire weight of the largest value item "just put it the bag...."   
      elif capacity >= val_item[0][1]:
          #update the weight of the bag
          capacity = capacity - val_item[0][1]

          #value * weight
          #print(val_item[0][0]*val_item[0][1])
          value_knap = value_knap + (val_item[0][0]*val_item[0][1])
          print(value_knap)
          val_item.pop(0)
  print(value_knap)




  return value_knap 





if __name__== "__main__":
  print (get_optimal_value (50,[60, 100, 120],[20, 50, 30]))
  #print(get_optimal_value(1000,[500],[30]))
  #print(get_optimal_value(10,[500],[30]))
  #print(500/30)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the issue you are trying to deal with. `value_knap` is a local variable in the function `get_optimal_value`. What exactly do you mean by "But when I access its value outside the while loop it just goes back to its original value."? What output are you seeing, and what output were you expecting?

Comment: @JohnHennig but isn't the value_knap variable global to the rest of the function? I also don't know what you mean by add scripts. Do you want to link my code to an online editor?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga when I print value_knap inside the while loop it updates the value. But when I print value_knap outside the loop it prints out 0, the initial value. I want to print out the update value from the while loop.

Comment: @JohnHennig if its possible. Can you please give me a link to an example of a stackoverflow post that has scripts output?

Comment: If you print `print("capacity, values", capacity, values)` in the `if` block and print `print('val*weight', val_item[0][0]*val_item[0][1])` in the `elif` block, you'll see that on your last iteration, capacity is `0.0`, so `value_knap = capacity * values[0]` -> `0.0`

Comment: @JohnHennig Thank you for breaking that term down for me. You've cleared up a lot of things for me with your statement. Now I know why I should never use the keyword **global** .