# Updating a str variable depending on outcome of an IF statement

Tags: python, if-statement, variables

I have a IF ELSE script that checks a number of items on a website to see if they are listed. I'm trying to set a string variable depending on the outcome of the IF statement - if the 'price-btn' class is present on the page then update the str variable with the link of the item (so I can use the same URL later on in my main script), but I can't get the str variable to update. It remains at its original 'pending' value.

```
    #set str variable
    linkvar = 'Pending'
    
    #URL's to check
    URL1 = '<link>'
    URL2 = '<link>'

    
    #Run the script that checks for the items
    def stock_check():
        page = requests.get(URL1)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        stockQuery = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "price-btn"})
        if stockQuery:
            print('This price is listed.')
            linkvar = 'URL1'
            return
        else:
            print('This price is not listed.')
    
        page = requests.get(URL2)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        stockQuery = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "price-btn"})
        if stockQuery:
            print('This price is listed.')
            linkvar = 'URL2'
            return
        else:
            print('This price is not listed.')
    stock_check()
    
    print('URL is:',linkvar)
```

This is the output I'm currently getting:

```
This price is not listed.
This price is listed.
URL: Pending
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: You are shadowing the variable. Look up variable scoping rules in Python. The simplest fix would be to add a `global` or `nonlocal` statement.

Comment: Here is a link that will help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911831/python-global-variable-not-updating

Comment: Change `linkvar = "URL2"` to `global linkvar = "URL2"`

Comment: Thanks, I have changed it to global linkvar and I now see the string "URL2" as the variable but why is it not actually storing the hyperlink for URL2 as the str var?