# Possible to access global variable from within pandas lambda function?

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to update the value of a global python variable from within a pandas lambda function?

I'm trying to

1. use the value of this global variable in my lambda function
2. change its value within the lambda function
3. use the updated value in lambda function that's called on the subsequent rows

I've tried to declare the value of my global variable outside of the lambda function, but it's not accessible from within the lambda function itself. I also tried to pass it using

```
def do_something(x, global_var):
   print(global_var)

   if global_var > 0:
      global_var = -1
      return x/2
   elif global_var <= 0:
      global_var = 1
      return 2*x


global_var = 5
df.apply(lambda x, global_var = global_var: do_something(x, global_var)
```

but updating `global_variable` from within the function doesn't update it globally. How, then, can I update the value of this variable from inside the lambda function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Global Variable not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911831/python-global-variable-not-updating)

Comment: Hi, can you update your code to an MWE so we can play around with it?

Comment: It's been my experience that when you start asking if you can do these sorts of things with a lambda, it's better to just use a function.

Comment: @Woodford this is perfect, I hadn't realized how to refer to global variables from within the lambda function. Thank you!

Comment: @mapf the comment by Woodford seems to have led me to the right place, I'll update the question to reflect this. Thank you for the looking into this!

Comment: There is *absolutely no difference* between how you refer to a global variable in a lambda expression and a full function definition statement

Comment: In any case, you aren't passing **a global variable** as a parameter, the parameter always gets *an object*. The parameter is merely a local variable in the function. Almost *certainly* trying to do this is a bad idea, there's *no good reason* that your `df.apply` should have a side effect, like updating a global variable. It makes no sense

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This is the sort of antagonistic response that turns people off of stack overflow. Not only did you fail to provide any helpful commentary, you deliberately made a comment after this question was closed.

Comment: @scrollex Antagonistic? What is antagonistic about it. I'm trying to explain the fundamental conceptual misunderstanding here. When you call a function, `f(x)` with some expression as an argument, that expression is evaluated to some object value, in this case, the expression `x` merely references some variable in the callers scope, but then `f` has *no idea* about that variable, it only has the object.

Comment: And of course, I'm trying to tell you that it is a bad idea for `apply` to have side-effects, it's designed for functional transformations of data. Also, I'm not sure how my having left a comment *after* the question was closed is supposed to be some sort of slight -- I can't exactly leave an answer anymore.

Comment: It is possible to achieve the same result, once declaring `global_var` as global inside `do_something`, by removing `global_var` from the parameters, and just calling `df.apply(do_something)`.  Or have I missed something?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you could've simply said what you said without reiterating that this is a nonsensical/bad idea multiple times, especially since, as you said, you don't know the use case. let me flip it on you: "it's almost always a _bad idea_ to tell people how wrong they are without having the full context of their use case. you have *no idea* what the use case is, and the intended use of of the apply function has *absolutely no bearing* on the specifics of use case"  — is that helpful? I can't imagine it is in any great way. I do, however, appreciate your last comment re: scope.

Comment: @Riley nope, that's exactly what I had in mind, and what I ended up doing after reading the top comment. I'd have added that as an answer but the question was closed. The core issue here was with me misunderstanding the use of global scope vs. local scope.