# Why does Python think I'm creating a variable when trying to cast?

Tags: python

I have a function (calculate) that references a variable outside of it (fill and empty) and it just won't detect that the variable already exists and tries to create one but I need that result for another function (render). Here is my code:

```
render = 0
isRunning = True
fill = ""
empty = ""
os.system('clear')

def calculate():
  for x in position:
    render = x
    if render == 0:
      empty = "-"
    if render == 1:
      fill = "⬛"

def render():
  if position[0] == 1:
    print(fill, empty)
  if position[0] == 0:
    print(empty, fill)
os.system('clear')

while isRunning:
  calculate()
  render()
  time.sleep(3)

  os.system('clear')
```

This is my new code after Pranav Hosangadi. I was confused on how to pass arguments into a function because I'm new to Python. This still doesn't work:

```
import time
import os
ant = "#"
position = [0, 1, 0]
render = 0
isRunning = True
fill = ""
empty = ""

def calculate(empty = empty, fill = fill):
  for x in position:
    render = x
    if render == 0:
      empty = "-"
    if render == 1:
      fill = "⬛"
  return fill, empty

def render_function():
  if position[0] == 1:
    print(fill, empty)
  if position[0] == 0:
    print(empty, fill)
os.system('clear')

while isRunning:
  calculate()
  render_function()
  time.sleep(3)
  os.system('clear')
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Your function `render()` overwrites the integer `render = 0`? Even if you fix the problem of referencing the global variable, nothing will happen when you do `calculate()` because `render` is a _function_, not an integer, and is never equal to `0` or `1`. Everybody is telling you to use global variables, but that [isn't always the best practice](//stackoverflow.com/q/19158339/843953). You should just pass the value of your integer to the function as an argument instead, and use `return` to return a value back.

Comment: As an aside, most modern languages will at least make it uncomfortable to reach outside the scope of a function and modify variables/names. In python's case, the `global` keyword. This is done for good reason as modifying global state within a function makes your code much more difficult to reason about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Global Variable not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911831/python-global-variable-not-updating)

Comment: The `render` variable seems to serve no purpose other than to copy the loop variable in that loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the global keyword:

```
x = "awesome"

def myfunc():
  x = "fantastic"
  print("Python is " + x)

myfunc()

print("Python is " + x)
```

returns

```
Python is fantastic
Python is awesome
```

using global,

```
x = "awesome"

def myfunc():
  global x
  x = "fantastic"

myfunc()

print("Python is " + x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `global` when modifying global variables (variables that you define in the top-level) inside functions:

```
def calculate():
  global render
  for x in position:
    render = x
    if render == 0:
      global empty
      empty = "-"
    if render == 1:
      global fill
      fill = "⬛"
```

Comment: This fixes the result of the problem. The problem is really using globals when they aren't needed in the first place though.

Comment: Also the function `render()` overwrites the integer `render = 0`?