# Can't update the value of i by clicking the button in python tkinter

Tags: python

i can't find that mistake in this clicker code. The i variable is not updating by clicking the "click" button. Please inform me if you find the mistake. Thank you!

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
i = 0

def numberchanger():
    i = i + 1

clicker = Button(text="click", bg="red", fg="green", font="Arial 20 bold", command=numberchanger)
clicker.place(x=600, y=400)
widget.title("Clicker")
clicknumber = Label(text=i, fg="blue", font="Arial 50 bold")
clicknumber.place(x=600, y=200)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `i` inside `numberchanger()` is a *local variable*, completely unrelated to the global variable of the same name.  The local variable has no initial value, so it's meaningless to add one to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Global Variable not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911831/python-global-variable-not-updating)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `global i` after `def numberchanger():`

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
i = 0

def numberchanger():
    global i
    i = i + 1
    print(i)
    clicknumber.config(text=i)


clicknumber = Label(text=i, fg="blue", font="Arial 50 bold")
clicknumber.place(x=600, y=200)

clicker = Button(text="click", bg="red", fg="green", font="Arial 20 bold", command=numberchanger)
clicker.place(x=600, y=400)
clicker.pack()
clicknumber.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No, sorry it doesn't work but thanks for the response

Comment: Try the code snippet in the update